# Is there a closed-form expression for the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n x^n}{1 - \left( \frac{x}{1+x} \right)^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

During a homework assignment, I ran into this series:
$$S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n x^n}{1 - \left( \frac{x}{1+x} \right)^n}$$
Graphing $S(x)$ shows that it converges for some values of $x$, mainly near $x=0$ and near $x=-1$. I was wondering if $S$ has a closed form. Despite my best efforts, I was not able to find one online or through my own analysis.

It should be noted that the summand is ill-defined for $n=0$. It does, however, possess a limit. In particular:
$$\lim_{n \to 0} \! \left ( \frac{n x^n}{1 - \left( \frac{x}{1+x} \right)^n} \right ) = \frac{1}{\ln \! \left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right)}$$
This limit should be taken as the $n=0$ term.

Comment: Mathematica doesn't know how to evaluate it (even starting from $n=1$).

Comment: For $x\approx0$, you can rewrite it as $\sum_\limits{k=0}^\infty\frac{x(\frac x{x+1})^k}{\left(x(\frac x{x+1})^k-1\right)^2}$. which has a closed form with the [Q-trigamma function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=QPolyGamma%5B1%2Ca%2Cb%5D) as $\frac{\psi^{(1)}_{\frac1x+1}\left(\frac{-\ln(x)}{\ln(\frac1x+1)}\right)}{\ln^2(\frac1x+1)}-\frac1{\ln(\frac1x+1)}$

Comment: That does seem to be true, at least without the $- \frac{1}{\ln \! \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right )}$ term (note that I explicitly included it). Is this a standard series? I can't find any reference to it.

Comment: To avoid the unpleasantness of $n=0$, you can use Gregory coefficients $G_k$ to expand the series. So something like: $$S(x)=1+x+ \sum _{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+1)^{k-1}} \left( (-1)^k G_k+\frac{x^k}{\left(1-x^k (x+1)^{1-k}\right)^2}\right)$$ Though I admit that doesn't really help for a closed form.

Comment: I found the continuous case.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer.*

The continuous case is interesting
$$ T(x) = \int_{1}^\infty \frac{n\, x^n}{1 - y^n}\,dn=\int_{1}^\infty\frac{n\, e^{a n}}{1-e^{b n}}\,dn$$ with $$  \qquad 0 < x < 1\qquad  \qquad y=\frac x{1+x}\qquad  \qquad a=\log(x)\qquad  \qquad b=\log(y)$$

$$\large\color{blue}{T(x)=\frac{e^a}{a\, b^2} \left(a\, \Phi \left(e^b,2,\frac{a}{b}\right)-b^2 \,\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{a}{b};\frac{a+b}{b};e^b\right)\right)}$$

If we *compare* with
$$ S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\, x^n}{1 - y^n}$$ (for $0.05 \leq x \leq 0.95$), we have a correlation coefficient  $R=0.999938$.

Comment: @JoieNL. What do you think I am currently working on ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Intriguing. Would a similar integral approximation be possible for $x \in (-2,-1]$?